# How to use grep for values <= smaller than equals bigger than equals?

Tags: r

I need to `grep` values between a certain range.
how would i write this?

I tried different things e.g.
for selecting everything between `0 and 1`   - call it A

```sh
mydata[grep("<=[1]",">=[0]") , mydata_V1, perl= TRUE ), "new_variable" <- "A"
```

Comment: Your question makes no sense as-is. Provide some context along with sample input and expected output.

Answer (score 1):

This Perl code uses a `grep` to select everything between 0 and 1 (inclusive).

```
my @mydata = (-0.1, 0, 0.1, 0.5, 1, 1.1);
my @selected = grep {0 <= $_ && $_ <= 1} @mydata;
```

Comment: Hi, I wanted to run this in R  - I forgot to mention. this code does not work in r? thanks

Comment: I suggest you remove the perl tag and replace it with R

Answer (score 1):

Your sample expression has syntax errors in it and I'm not sure exactly what it was meant to be, but I think what you want is logical indexing:

```
> mydata <- runif(20, 0, 2)
> mydata[mydata >= 0 & mydata <= 1] <- NA
> mydata
 [1]       NA       NA 1.655342 1.704777       NA 1.026898       NA       NA
 [9]       NA 1.316825       NA 1.498825       NA       NA 1.263354       NA
[17]       NA 1.389281       NA 1.041297
```

Note the use of `&` instead of `&&`.  This will not work if you use `&&`.

See http://www.cookbook-r.com/Basics/Indexing_into_a_data_structure/ for more examples (including how to do this to multidimensional data structures).